# Post types disappeared

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the following in functions.php of my custom theme:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( "main-slider", 671, 252, true );

add_action( 'init', 'create_main_slider_post_type' );
add_action( 'init', 'create_external_link_post_type' );

function create_main_slider_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'main_slider_item',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                                  'name' => __( 'Main Slider Items' ),
                                  'singular_name' => __( 'Main Slider Item' ),
                                  'menu_name' => __( 'Main Slider' )
                        ),
                        'description' => "A banner with a text and button",
                        'public' => false,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'exclude_from_search' => true,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                        'map_meta_cap' => false,
                        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
                        'has_archive' => false,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        )
    );
}

function create_external_link_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'external_link',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                                  'name' => __( 'External Links' ),
                                  'singular_name' => __( 'External Link' ),
                        ),
                        'description' => "A link with image for site footer",
                        'public' => false,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'exclude_from_search' => true,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                        'map_meta_cap' => false,
                        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
                        'has_archive' => false,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        )
    );
}
?>
```

This code works, as this is confirmed by seeing "Main Slider" and "External Links" in the dashboard.

In config of "Advanced Custom Fields" there disappeared main_slider_item as a possible value for "Post Type". (It shows only "post" and "page" post content types.) It was there earlier.

Where to dig?

I tried to disable every active plugin, but this hasn't helped.

Comment: "*In config of "Advanced Custom Fields" there disappeared main_slider_item as a possible value for "Post Type". (It shows only "post" and "page" post content types.) It was there earlier.*" - So, **what changed** between then and now? Did you update core, your Theme, any Plugins? Any other changes?

Comment: And **PLEASE** follow your other Qs, before adding new ones. Thank you.

Comment: @Chip Bennett: I don't remember what exactly I have changed. But I've tried to disable every other plugin except of Advanced Custom Fields. This does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For post type to appear I need to see `'public' => true,` in register_post_type().